# Python list search against Raw_input

Tags: python-2.7

I'm very new to coding and could do with your help!
Please see below the code which I need to get working;

```
pick_car = raw_input("So whats your favourite car brand then?").lower()
#If raw input contains the name of a car in the cars list then print vehicle brand below
if pick_car in cars:
    print 'okay so you like ' + #Car from list
```

I have a few lists located at the top of my code, one named cars which contains a lot of vehicle brands.

Comment: Shouldn't `+ pick_car` do the job?

Comment: yes but if a person types " yes I like bmw" it will print the full user input and not register the bmw in the cars list. I need it to be able to search the raw input for any word in the cars list and just return the name of the car.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input`, as mentioned in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) will return a string type object.
Now, to check if any brand name appears in the string, instead of checking if `pick car` is appearing in `cars`, we will check if any brand name from `cars` appears in `pick cars`, like so:

```
pick_car = raw_input("So whats your favourite car brand then?").lower()
for brand_name in cars:
    if brand_name in pick_car:
        print 'okay so you like ' + brand_name
```

Comment: yes but if a person types " yes I like bmw" it will print the full user input and not register the bmw in the cars list. I need it to be able to search the raw input for any word in the cars list and just return the name of the car.

Comment: Please check my edit. Next time provide examples of inputs and desired outputs for a more clarified question.

Comment: Thank you that seems to have worked.
Brand name is not defined anywhere within my code and when I use it later on in the code it defaults to the first string in my list. could you explain how this for Brand_name works or send me a link to something. Thanks

Comment: @Dantheman90 `brand_name` is defined in the for loop. I highly recommend you to read more about them.